# How to continue an OpenMP directive on the next line in free-from Fortran?

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a line of a Fortran code, e.g.,

```
    !$omp do private(aa, bb, cc) schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:alpha, beta, gamma)
```

Suppose this line contains several arguments and the length exceeds 132 characters, gfortran will lead to error message. I tried to use `&` to break the line. But I am not sure how to start the next line. As other case, directly start the next line without `!` leads to `Error: Syntax error in OpenMP variable list at (1)`.

How to break the 132 characters limit for omp line?

Comment: Thanks. I shall try. I use gfortran 4.8.5 :( ifort can surpass this limit, I think.

Comment: Wow, by ```!$omp ``` after ``` &``` in the previous line works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just to link the other form, the fixed form is treated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704732/syntax-for-openmp-long-directive-list-fortran77

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write multiline omp statements by ending with `&` and staring a newline with `$omp`.

Example

```pascal
!$omp do private(aa, bb, cc) &
!$omp schedule(dynamic)      &
!$omp reduction(+:alpha, beta, gamma) 
...
!$omp end do
```